How to handle Ctrl+C when executing a process using Go Docker SDK?
I have a Docker container running indefinitely with a default command tail -f /dev/null that I created and started using Go Docker SDK:
...
config := &container.Config{
    Image:        "test",
    Tty:          true,
    OpenStdin:    true,
    AttachStdin:  true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
}

hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
}

createResp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(context.Background(), config, hostConfig, nil, nil, "test")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

err := cli.ContainerStart(context.Background(), createResp.ID, container.StartOptions{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
...


Now I'd like to run a python script that is inside this container, that I could cancel with Ctrl+C. For example:
import time

while True:
    print("Press Ctrl+C to exit")
    time.sleep(1)

By using Docker CLI to execute the script, it is correctly interrupted:
docker exec -it test python3 main.py
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../.../main.py", line 25, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

But I'm having issues reproducing this behaviour using the SDK. After looking over the Internet (and asking ChatGPT), so far I have the following code:
...
execConfig := container.ExecOptions{
    Cmd:          []string{"python3", "main.py"},
    Tty:          true,
    AttachStdin:  true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
}

execCreateResp, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, containerID, execConfig)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

execOpts := container.ExecStartOptions{
    Tty: true,
}
execResp, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, execCreateResp.ID, execOpts)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer execResp.Close()

signalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(signalChannel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

go func() {
    _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, execResp.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading output:", err)
    }
}()

<-signalChannel
fmt.Println("Received Ctrl+C, stopping command...")
...

The Ctrl+C is captured but the execution is not interrupted:
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
^CReceived Ctrl+C, stopping command...
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Press Ctrl+C to exit

How could I fix this behavior? Any help would be appreciated.

Why do you need a container running tail?  Can you just run a new container with the Python process?  That might be easier to control than an exec session.

Maybe I went the wrong way, but my goal is to be able within the same container to run this script multiple times with potentially different inputs, or maybe a different script that was packaged...

Why "within the same container", though?  A container is normally a wrapper around a single process; in the same way you'd normally just run a subprocess and not try to "go inside" it without Docker, I'd just run a new container every time you need one of these executions.
